# Google Geocoding API to geometry (Multi-line string)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding

I am using the Google [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#Sensor). I need to use that response and convert that to geometry. How is this possible? What postgis function should I use and what parameters to assign?

Raw JSON data:

```
"geometry":{
   "bounds":{
      "northeast":{
         "lat":35.1614839,
         "lng":33.3903832
      },
      "southwest":{
         "lat":35.1595564,
         "lng":33.3889372
      }
   },
   "location":{
      "lat":35.1602836,
      "lng":33.389555
   },
   "location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
   "viewport":{
      "northeast":{
         "lat":35.1618691302915,
         "lng":33.3910091802915
      },
      "southwest":{
         "lat":35.1591711697085,
         "lng":33.3883112197085
      }
   }
}
```

[image: Geocoding API Response]

Comment: Can you paste the raw JSON data here?

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to import into the DB, with Python code and the range of different geometries that you expect, since the provided answer from@LeonPowałka does precisely what you ask for in the question. You can easily serialize any WKT geometry from the Geocoding API *in Python* (concatenate the coordinates), and call `INSERT INTO <table> (SELECT ST_GeomFromText(<WKT_string>, 4326));`

Comment: It must be multi-line string. I updated the question title.

Comment: Please describe how the line should be constructed. The data you provided is a geocoding result and therefore a point type.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here is an image of how the existing geometry points look like on the map. Converting that to WKT returns a very long text https://i.imgur.com/G4Z4CD8.png. I need to store the data provided by google as multi line string, if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block example operates on the json input you provided.

Documentation links that I used:

constructing point: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html

operating on json: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

```
create or replace function parse_response(p_resp json)
returns text
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    v_lat float;
    v_lng float;
begin 
    v_lat := p_resp->'geometry'->'location'->'lat';
    v_lng := p_resp->'geometry'->'location'->'lng';
    return st_astext(st_point(v_lng, v_lat));
end $$;

--returns point in WKT format
select parse_response('{"geometry":{
   "bounds":{
      "northeast":{
         "lat":35.1614839,
         "lng":33.3903832
      },
      "southwest":{
         "lat":35.1595564,
         "lng":33.3889372
      }
   },
   "location":{
      "lat":35.1602836,
      "lng":33.389555
   },
   "location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
   "viewport":{
      "northeast":{
         "lat":35.1618691302915,
         "lng":33.3910091802915
      },
      "southwest":{
         "lat":35.1591711697085,
         "lng":33.3883112197085
      }
   }
}}')
```

Comment: my question is not how to read json in postgres. I do it with python. I want to convert that data provided by google into geometry

Comment: Into geometry where? In the database? And then do what with it? The code I made takes your google data as a parameter and returns geometry

Comment: Yes into geometry. Then i can show it using openlayers. Converting that to WKT

Comment: Well I edited the function to return geometry in WKT format based on the data. Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I think it's better the function parameters to be lon / lat. No need to read that json. I call the function from python. Also it will be multi line string and not point

Comment: Why do you need PostGIS for this? You said you have it in Python and want to display it in OpenLayers.

Comment: well, your approach is correct but it should be multiline string not point

Comment: This can be rewritten using ST_MakeLine. Which points are supposed to make the line? The data you provided seems to be a point type only.